# Are my passwords safe in an apk

Tags: android, database

Let's say I want to access an online database from my android app. I will have to enter my username and password. But are my credentials safe if I do this?
Would it be possible for a hacker to decompile my apk and get the password for example?
If it isn't safe, what should I do, send a request to a php script on a private server?

Comment: when you communicate with the server by providing your id and password, are you going to store those credentials in the application database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Things:

-Never connect to a database directly from the android app. It is considered bad practise and for good reasons, you can potentially expose queries and other info/code if someone reverses your apk, but there's other reasons aswell...

Instead, use REST service:
From client you will only send http requests to specific server files/servlet that will retrieve back the information you need (normally using JSON) from the database or other sources. You can also authenticate by this means using POST form.

-Your credentials would be safe from reverse engineering (mainly because they are not hard coded...) but could be potentially withdrawn through hotspots by phishing into your connection.

For that reason, it's better to use encription before sending these credentials to the server. You should easily find default support for md5 or SHA.

However you should take a look into Oauth protocol implementations as for user authentication, for reliability in larger projects with much interoperability which potentially risks user credentials unless your software uses validated tokens of sort.

Comment: Ok thanks, if I use MongoDb, are there any REST services available?

Comment: Not familiar with MongoDb, but normally REST design is pretty straightforward (and self-explanatory) and unless dealing with very complex solutions that need multiple level architecture I wouldnt recommend any specific API for that matter... (except maybe for PUSH). If all you need to do is retrieve database data or queries, it's much more recommended to do it from scratch.

Comment: Ok, got it. So if I wanted to get info about an user as a JSON file, I would have to call script.php?user=bob this script doing all the hard work

Comment: Exactly, from client simply use http request with post/get data, then retrieve the JSON served by the php file which access the database.

Comment: No problem, thanks to you for CA. Remember that it is also recomended that you encrypt/decript user/password credentials during http request to make hotspot sniffing harder.
Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

1) it is not "not safe", it is dangerous.
2) even a stupid person like me can decompile apk, not to mention real hacker
3) one possible solution is to implement user authentication. actually, it depends on what you want   to do actually

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not safe in an APK-  its trivial to decompile one.  Sending it via an HTTPS web service is much safer.  But really, you don't want to access a db from your app directly-  its a security risk, you need to allow your db an open port to the internet.  Instead you should use a web service to serve the data to your app.  That way only the web server has direct access to the db, a firewall can keep the rest of the internet away.

Comment: So what I need to do is like send a request to https://mysite/dataaccess.php?user=foo&pass=bar and get a JSON file with info about my user?

Answer (score 0):

***Do basic authentication -***

As mentioned in [httpclient-4-basic-authentication](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication),

> In general, we recommend minimizing the frequency of asking for user
>   credentials -- to make phishing attacks more conspicuous, and less
>   likely to be successful. Instead use an authorization token and
>   refresh it.
>
> Where possible, username and password should not be stored on the
>   device. Instead, perform initial authentication using the username and
>   password supplied by the user, and then use a short-lived,
>   service-specific authorization token.

```
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http");
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
new UsernamePasswordCredentials(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS));

AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());

// Add AuthCache to the execution context
final HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
context.setAuthCache(authCache);
```

For best, in storing credentials use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

As mentioned in official dev docs -

> This class provides access to a centralized registry of the user's
>   online accounts. The user enters credentials (username and password)
>   once per account, granting applications access to online resources
>   with "one-click" approval.

More of a read [security-tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#UserData).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to save your credentials in the application as Hard coded for validations, it could be always harmful. but if you use JSON or some other WebServices and send your credentials for validation to the server. Then they are more secular than saving them on your application itself. Let the validation be performed on the PHP script on the server rather than on your application end.

Answer (score 0):

If your application can do sth without user providing credentials anyone, who has access to apk file, can do this. So if your app is communicating with some databases, storages or sth anyone can access them.

You can try some techniques to hide password in apk, but it only make it a little bit harder.

This means, you have four possibilities:

1. Don't connect to external database at all.
2. Use some intermediate server. It will means that anyone can use your database through this server, but server at least can limit access to this databse.
3. Don't store any credentials, but ask user for them.
4. Store credentials in apk and let everyone use your database.